# How to install Python 3rd party libgmail-0.1.11.tar.tar into Python in Windows XP home?

Tags: python

I do not know Python, I have installed it only and downloaded the libgmail package. So, please give me verbatim steps in installing the libgmail library. My python directory is c:\python26, so please do not skip any steps in the answer.

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help this question can now be closed. I have many good methods to install and use the libgmail library. 

Thanks again! 

Antone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is extract it, and put it somewhere (I prefer the Libs folder in your Python directory). Then read the readme. It explains that you need to do:

```
python setup.py
```

in your command line. Then you're done.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help - there are 10 files extracted where do they all go? In the libs directory there is only one file per library such as "winsound.lib or select.lib, does not seem right to stick 10 file in that directory. 

Thanks for the help!

Comment: In any even when I run the command "python setup.py from the libgmail directory using a DOS box, I get the below message.
______________________________________________________________

c:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\libgmail>python setup.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 7, in <module>
    import libgmail
  File "C:\Users\Antone\Desktop\libgmail-0.1.11\libgmail.py", line 36, in <modul
e>
    import mechanize as ClientCookie
ImportError: No module named mechanize

Comment: That means you need mechanize, do you happen to have that module? If not, you need to download it.

Comment: guess not i am using python 2.6, do you know where I can get if from?

Comment: do not see a windows version on linux version?

Comment: There is a zip file on the download site for mechanize, http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/#download . It too has a README and an INSTALL.txt that you can read, however I'm sure the install is just python setup.py to install.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way might be to install [easy_install](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) using the instructions at that page and then typing the following at the command line:

```
easy_install libgmail
```

If it can't be found, then you can point it directly to the file that you downloaded:

```
easy_install c:\biglongpath\libgmail.zip
```

Comment: easy_install is not available on a clean python 2.6 installation.

Comment: That's why I suggested installing easy_install first and then using it to install the library.

Comment: Oh, yes. I missed that suggestion.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help this question can not be closed. I have many good methods to install and use the libgmail library. 

Thanks again!

Antone

Answer (score 2):

Extract the archive to a temporary directory, and type "python setup.py **install**".

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you downloaded and unzipped it to `C:/libgmail-0.1.11`. Open a command prompt and:

```
cd C:/libgmail-0.1.11
```

Then build an Windows installer:

```
python setup.py bdist --format=wininst
```

Then go to  `C:/libgmail-0.1.11/dist` and you'll find an installer. Double click it, follow the "next" procedure and you're done.

What's nice about this method is that you can easily uninstall the library from Control Panel/Add or Remove Programs.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it:

1. Make sure C:\Python26 and C:\Python26\scripts are both on your system path.
2. Install [setuptools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools).  You'll have to download the source distribution, and extract it.  You will likely need something like [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) for this.  If you use 7zip note that you will need to extract it twice.  Once to get a .tar file, and again to get a directory out of that tar file.

   - Open a command prompt and cd to the directory you created.  Run the command `python setup.py install`.
3. Run the command `easy_install mechanize`.
4. Install libgmail just like you did setuptools.

This was a lot of work, but you now have the `easy_install` tool available to simplify installing these kinds of things in the future.  If you're doing anything serious, you may also want to consider setting up a [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv/1.3.3) and using [pip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip/0.4) instead of `easy_install`.